# Code any where returns commented PHPcode

Tags: php, html, codeanywhere

When I put some PHP code in `index.php`, my PHP code does not show up in my browser (I use firefox). In Firefox's dev tool the PHP code

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

becomes

```
 <!--?php include 'header.php';  ?-->
```

It is on Codeanywhere, HTML container on Ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, PHP is server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to see the tutorial first. http://docs.codeanywhere.com/quicktutorial.html